# Let $f(x,y)=\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {y^2}{4}$ on $\{(x,y)|x^2-y^2=2\}$. Find the absolute maximum and minimum if they exist.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f(x,y)=\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {y^2}{4}$ on $\{(x,y)|x^2-y^2=2\}$. Find the absolute maximum and minimum if they exist.

I approached this problem using lagrange multiplier, with $g(x,y)=x^2-y^2-2$.

$f_x=x, f_y=y$ and $g_x=2x, g_y=-2y$. Setting these equal, I got $1=2\lambda$ and $-1=2\lambda$, which has no solution.

Can someone please tell me where I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Minimize a one variable function by substituting $y^2$ by $x^2-2$.

Comment: I would rather propose $\dfrac{x^2}{2} = 1+\dfrac{y^2}{2}$. But it's the same really.

Comment: Isn't $ \ f_y \ = \frac{y}{2} \ $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the actual question, you should be getting three equalities:

$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
x-2\lambda x & = 0, \\
y/2+2\lambda y & =0, \\
x^2-y^2 & =2 \end{array} \right.$$

So you know that $y=0$ and hence that $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, in short, OP should not have simply divided $ \ \frac{y}{2} \ = \ - 2y \cdot \lambda \ , $ as that "discards" the solution $ \ y = 0 \ . $